# Error Assertion failed in Wijmo: Date expected

Tags: angular, wijmo

I am using Wijmo date picker. I am getting an error when I send proper date format for Wijmo date. Sometimes the same date is picked without error, sometimes an error is displaying.

I am setting form value this.mfForm.get('date').setValue('15/12/2019');

Every time the date value will change on button click.

Comment: Could you also share the code? It's kind of hard to help just from few lines of text.

Comment: @LeBavarois this.myForm.get('date').setValue('15/12/2019');

Answer (score 1):

The Wijmo InputDate control accepts the date in the format 'MM/dd/yyyy' by default. So, you will need to provide the date in this format:

```
this.myForm.get('date').setValue('12/15/2019');
```